# Loading webp image using Volley

Tags: android, android-volley

Using volley to load image of type webp work for android 5.0 version but when trying on device with android version 4.1 it dont work

The exception i get on volley on error response simply print null

```
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
Log.e(Utils.TAG, "Image Load Error: " +error.getMessage());
                }
```

When looking on android developer docs [Supported media formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) it states that webp is supported in:

> (Android 4.0+)
>   (Lossless, Transparency, Android 4.2.1+)

So what does it mean i can load webp images using volley on 4.1 android devices?

Comment: Yes but transparency and lossless will not work for 4.1

Comment: But still volley throws exception on android 4.1